# error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token ===

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

we are stuck in a problem in angular. if we run the angular 16 project with micro-frontend then we see this error

> error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token ===

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition `*ngIf="optionalFieldValue==='password'"` To `*ngIf="optionalFieldValue=='password'"`

When you try to use the === operator in a template, which is not allowed in Angular templates, comparison operator to use in Angular templates is`==` or `!=`.

https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Comment: If we add *ngIf="optionalFieldValue=='password'"  then show Expected `===` but received `==`eslint@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq  error.

Comment: update `.eslintrc.json` file 
`{
  "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "allow-null-check": true
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: i have already this but showing same error:

.eslintrc.json file {   "rules": {     "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": [       "error",       "always",       {         "allow-null-check": true       }     ]   } }

Comment: Check EsLint latest verison and try to reinstall and restart the eslint. Check are you using Angular ESLint or any other ESLint plugin?

Comment: Paste the new error are you still using `===`?

Answer (score 0):

What is optionalFieldValue type is your ts file:
how did you define this variable and how does it get data?
these problems usually occurs when the types are not accurately provided.